# Is the functor $O$ from the simplex category to the category of orientals cofinal

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Let $\Delta$ be the full subcategory of the category of small categories spanned by the non-empty totally ordered sets of the form $[n]$ for $n \geq 0$. Let $\mathfrak{O}$ be the full subcategory of the category of small $\omega$-categories spanned by the orientals $O(n) $ for $n \geq0$.

Is the functor $O: \Delta \to \mathfrak{O}$ that sends $[n] $ to the n-th oriental $O(n)$
cofinal, final, respectively?

Comment: Both categories have terminal objects so one of these questions has the answer "trivially, yes". The one that has to do with colimits indexed by these categories. But I can't keep straight if that's "final" or "cofinal".

Answer (score 3):

There are really four questions here: is $O : \Delta \to \mathfrak O$ initial, final, homotopy initial, or homotopy final? **The answer to all these questions is *yes*!**

Here "initial" means that $\Delta \downarrow O[n]$ is always connected, "homotopy initial" means that $\Delta \downarrow O[n]$ is weakly contractible, "final" means that $O[n] \downarrow \Delta$ is connected, and "homotopy final" means that $O[n] \downarrow \Delta$ is weakly contractible. In other words, "initial" means that 1-categorical limits indexed by $\mathfrak O$ may be computed using their restriction along $O$, "homotopy initial" means that $\infty$-categorical limits indexed by $\mathfrak O$ may be computed this way, "final" means that 1-categorical colimits may be computed this way, and "homotopy final" means that $\infty$-categorical colimits may be computed this way. See the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+%28infinity%2C1%29-functor).

As mentioned in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445644/is-the-functor-o-from-the-simplex-category-to-the-category-of-orientals-cofina#comment1151130_445644), the functor $O: \Delta \to \mathfrak O$ is trivially **final**, and **homotopy final** because both categories have terminal objects.

The functor $O : \Delta \to \mathfrak O$ is **initial**. To see this, observe that every $f \in \Delta \downarrow O[n]$ admits a map from some $g : O[0] \to O[n]$. Moreover, since the 1-skeleton of $O[n]$ is connected, it's easy to see that all of the maps $g : O[0] \to O[n]$ can be connected via zigzags through maps $h : O[1] \to O[n]$. Thus the category $\Delta \downarrow O[n]$ is connected as desired.

In fact, the functor $O : \Delta \to \mathfrak O$ is **homotopy initial**. To see this, consider the composite functor $\Delta \downarrow O[n] \xrightarrow F \Delta \downarrow O[n+1] \xrightarrow G \Delta \downarrow O[n]$, where

$$F : (O[k] \xrightarrow f O[n]) \mapsto (O[k] \ast O[0] \xrightarrow{f \ast O[0]} O[n] \ast O[0]) = (O[k+1] \to O[n+1])$$

takes the join with a point, and where

$$G : (O[k+1] \xrightarrow g O[n+1]) \mapsto (O[k+1] \xrightarrow g O[n+1] \xrightarrow {s_n} O[n])$$

postcomposes the last degeneracy.

Note that there is a natural transformation $Id \Rightarrow GF$ from the identity and another natural transformation $const_{O[0] \xrightarrow{\{n\}} O[n]} \Rightarrow GF$ from the constant map at the "last" object. Thus after passing to geometric realizations, the identity, $GF$, and the constant map all become homotopic, i.e. $\Delta \downarrow O[n]$ is weakly contractible.

Comment: @ Tim Campion Thanks a lot! This clarifies my question. Is it also true that the functors $\Delta \downarrow [n] \to \Delta \downarrow \mathcal{O}[n], \Delta \uparrow [n] \to \Delta \uparrow \mathcal{O}[n]$ are homotopy initial/ homotopy final?